# Confusion after attempting to apply chain rule with respect to matrix, using a Frobenius product.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

Consider a loss function 
$$ j = \frac{1}{2}||e||^2,$$
where $e=y-t,\quad$ $y=f(x,u) \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\quad$ $u=Wx \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now I want to find the gradient of $j$ with respect to the $m\times n$ matrix $W$, i.e. $\frac{\partial j}{\partial W}$ in order to minimize $j$.

Let us denote the Frobenius inner product $A:B = \text{tr}(A^TB)$. 
We can then write 
$$\begin{aligned}
j & = \frac{1}{2}e:e, \\
dj & = e : de \\
& = (y-t):dy \\
& = (y-t):df(x,u).
\end{aligned}$$

Now I got confused after this step, as I want to write $df(x,u)$ in terms of the gradient $\frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial u}$ and $u$, but I cannot say that $df(x,u)$ equals $\frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial u}:du$, since $f(x,u)$ is not a scalar!

So how do I proceed in writing out a differential of a vector ($f(x,u)$)?
If I have this term, I intend to proceed with the chain rule in order to find $du$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u & = Wx,\\
du & = d(Wx) = d(W) x.
\end{aligned}
$$
Then I would expect to end up with $df(x,u)$ being a function of the gradient $\frac{\partial f(x,u)}{\partial u}$ and $dW$ so I can find the final gradient $\frac{\partial j}{\partial W}$.

So in short, what is the correct way to apply the chain rule on $df(x,u)$ with respect to $W$, and are there some general rules concerning the frobenius inner product and the chain rule that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typing convenience, let
$$\eqalign{
 G &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times m} \cr
}$$
and note the following differentials
$$\eqalign{
  df &= G\,du \cr
  du &= dW\,x \cr
}$$
Then picking up where you got stuck
$$\eqalign{
dj &= (y-t):df \cr
  &= e:df \cr
  &= e:G\,du \cr
  &= G^Te:du \cr
  &= G^Te:dW\,x \cr
  &= G^Tex^T:dW \cr
\frac{\partial j}{\partial W}  &= G^Tex^T \cr\cr
}$$
There are rules for manipulating a mixture of Frobenius products and other products
$$\eqalign{
 A:BC &= B^TA:C &= AC^T:B &\,\,\,\text{ (Frobenius-Matrix)}\cr
 A:B\odot C &= B\odot A:C &= A\odot C:B &\,\,\,\text{ (Frobenius-Hadamard)}\cr
}$$
There are also rules for Kronecker product mixtures
$$\eqalign{
(A\otimes B)(X\otimes Y) &= (AX)\otimes(BY) &\,\,\,\text{ (Kronecker-Matrix)}\cr
(A\otimes B):(X\otimes Y) &= (A:X)\otimes(B:Y) &\,\,\,\text{ (Kronecker-Frobenius)}\cr
(A\otimes B)\odot(X\otimes Y) &= (A\odot X)\otimes(B\odot Y) &\,\,\,\text{ (Kronecker-Hadamard)}\cr
}$$
and rules for functions commonly used in matrix decompositions and transforms
$$\eqalign{
\def\op{\operatorname}
\def\tr{\op{tr}}
\def\vc{\op{vec}}
\def\sym{\op{sym}}
\def\skew{\op{skew}}
\def\iso{\op{iso}}
\def\dev{\op{dev}}
\def\fft{\op{FFT}}
\sym(A) &\equiv\tfrac12(A+A^T)
  \qquad&\skew(A)\equiv A-\sym(A) \\
\iso(A) &\equiv\left[\frac{\tr(A)}{\tr(I)}\right]I
  \qquad&\;\;\dev(A)\equiv A-\iso(A) \\
\\
\sym(A):B &= A:\sym(B)
  \qquad&\sym(A):\skew(B) = 0 \\
\skew(A):B &= A:\skew(B) \\
\iso(A):B &= A:\iso(B)
  \qquad&\;\;\iso(A):\dev(B) = 0 \\
\dev(A):B &= A:\dev(B) \\
\fft(A):B &= A:\fft(B) \\
A:B &= \vc(A):\vc(B) \\
}$$